# Adding Facebook "Like" button to Fancybox (jquery.fancybox.pack.js // fancyBox v2.1.5)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, joomla3.0

I am trying to add a Facebook "Like" feature inside a fancybox, similar to http://jsfiddle.net/B9ytK/

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }  
});
```

The question has been raised before:

[How to modify jquery.fancybox.pack.js file to add share buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460203/how-to-modify-jquery-fancybox-pack-js-file-to-add-share-buttons)

but the answer didn't really help, since it wasn't really answered.

My diffrence is that I use Joomla rather than WP, but the question is the same. Where should I add the code from the JSFiddle, since I don't really "call" Fancybox, it's a Joomla-loaded plugin.

To make matters worse, the plugin loads the packed version of fancybox so it is really hard to read the code.

I am not even able to add a line of text to the fancybox, so this would also be considered enough to get me further.

I would be thankful for any help,

Søren

Comment: you don't have to modify the original (compressed or not) fancybox js file. you need to add a custom js code (as in the jsfiddle) either inline or in a separated js file and call it from your joomla template

Comment: it's also documented here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.6

Comment: I have read the help file from Fancyapp before I came here and I've gotten the jsfiddle code to work on a non-joomla website (laravel). I am pretty new to JS so adding code is not a trivial thing for me. I will see if I can somehow call it from the template or alternatively simply stop using the plugin and call fancybox/lightbox as I have done in the non-joomla website.